# One JavaScript code file for multiple locations

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jakarta-ee, dry, redundancy

We are developing multiple Java EE applications (8 for the moment) that are all based on the same sort of code. However, all the apps are clearly separated as different projects in Eclipse, they all have their own folder on Windows Explorer, and they all have their own repo on the Git server.

The idea was to put the redundant code somewhere (another project named "core"), and use it on every apps automatically without having to recode the same thing 8 times.
For the Java part, we did a "link source" in each project, which create sort of a symlink inside Eclipse to the "core" project, and use the specified "core" package in Java source with no problem.

But it doesn't work so well for the JavaScript/CSS part. I have absolutely no clue about how to code my redundant JS/CSS onto the "core" project, and use it elsewhere without having to manually copy it each and every time I modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look into git for a solution to your problem. After all you still want the js file to be included in every project, but be maintained in a seperate project (as far as I understand it). There ought to be some sort of submodules and/or commit-handles or whatever to solve this using git.

Comment: I finally get around to it, and yeah, that's exactly what i wanted. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the User Library functionality in the JavaScript Include Path properties of your project is for.

Comment: This is a Java project (and more specifically a Tomcat project), so here what's available to me in the properties : http://i49.tinypic.com/1zx1vd0.png